# SSL Error when trying to download a Java JDK

Tags: java, oracle, security

I need to download a particular version of the Java JDK, so I'm going to Oracle's website to do so. When I click any of the links to begin downloading a JDK, I get the following error message from my browser:

> ## This is probably not the site you are looking for!
>
> You attempted to reach download.oracle.com, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as a248.e.akamai.net. This may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious. An attacker on your network could be trying to get you to visit a fake (and potentially harmful) version of download.oracle.com.
>
> You should not proceed, especially if you have never seen this warning before for this site.

Is this normal (i.e., does Oracle use akamai.net to host its JDK distributions), or does this suggest that Oracle or I are being attacked?

Comment: I considered asking this question on Security.SE, but I believe it is best on StackOverflow for two reasons: (1) It is about the JDK, which is a programming tool, which is on-topic. (2) If Oracle is using akamai.net for hosting its JDKs, many other programmers might have the same question, and questions on StackOverflow are easier to find than ones on StackExchange.SE, so the question is a better canonical resource here.

Comment: Akamai Technologies (akamai.com) is a pretty important player in the internet. HOWEVER - this web address does not appear to have anything to do with akamai.com. I suggest an abundantly cautious approach. Can you tell us what specific version of the JDK you were trying to download, and how you got there?

Comment: This just happened to me. I think my 'https everywhere' extension it trying to force the site to use https, but the site doesn't want to.

Comment: I'm seeing this same error for `jdk-7u67-macosx-x64.dmg` on [this download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html).

Comment: Same happens to me: Chrome 38.0.2125.104 with "HTTPS Everywhere" and [java 8 update 25](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u25-b17/jdk-8u25-macosx-x64.dmg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither Sun nor Oracle has ever used third parties to host JDK downloads in my experience since 1997.

Comment: I hit the same problem, and I also use HTTPS Everywhere. While doing a bit of research, I did discover that Oracle seems to be making use of Akamai for downloads, at least for some stuff. See https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/entry/public_yum_now_powered_by